# How to redirect from subdomain to another subdomain in IIS Redirect module

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis

I have an application and there are subdomains (or subfolders), which point to different customers

I want to redirect from one subfolder to another using IIS Rewrite module.

How can i achive that.

For example

Actual Url : 
http://example.com/initial/home/index?Id=1
should be redirected to
http://example.com/final/home/index?Id=1

http://example.com/initial
should be redirected to
http://example.com/final

http://example.com/initial/test.aspx
should be redirected to
http://example.com/final/test.aspx

All domains are aliases in the Default Web Site in IIS. example.com/initial is an application added under Default Web Site with alias initial and example.com/final is an application added under Default Web Site with alias named final. They are all pointing to the same application folder.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: How did you address your domains in code? If you put some part of your code you can get better helps and answers.

Comment: All domains are aliases in the Default Web Site in IIS. example.com/initial is an application added under Default Web Site with alias initial and example.com/final is an application added under Default Web Site with alias named final. They are all pointing to the same application folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could use below url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="app redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/initial/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sitetest.com/final/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

[image]
[image]

Note:
You could modify hostname as per your requirement. 
If you did not installed the url rewrite module first installed it by using web platform installer or manually.

[URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: thank you. this partially worked but

i need this rule for example:

http://example.com/test should be redirected to http://example.com/test2

but this time it does not work

Comment: what is the test and test2 folder or application? in the original post you described something different.